# How to program the robot Pepper in Choregraphe to make a tour

Tags: python, nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

I'm working on a project with Pepper with the Choregraphe tool and i need to find a box or anything to help me to make the robot make a tour in a room. I know that I can save the coordinates and make the robot move but, what happen if I move the robot? Then all the boxes should not work.

I don't have the robot in my hands yet because of the pandemic but watching the move boxes I am not sure what i will do.

I guess I should need to use the `ALNavigation` but I do not think that this will be enough.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best luck will be to use `ALNavigation`, yes.
But on 2.5 it is not very reliable.
You can upgrade to 2.9 and use the action [`LocalizeAndMap`](https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch4_api/movement/reference/localize_and_map.html#localize-and-map).
If you move the robot manually, it will try maintain a good accuracy of the localization, but it is limited.
Note that it can still happen that in a large room, or in absence of good visual contrast, the robot may still lose itself.

Comment: Hi, i'm not sure what will be the version of the robot or if i can change it. But if i can upgrade it, it is posible to use LocalizeAndMap in Choregraphe? I mean, i don't have enough time to start all the work again in Android Studio and in Java. Thanks!

Comment: No, sadly you will have to rewrite it. Then `ALNavigation` is your best chance. The robot uses vision and odometry to assess its location, and will try to keep track of it when you move it. But the performances are not great.